# Conflicto con dos clases por las Conexion a la base de datos

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

```
<?php

include "Log.php";
include "Salida.php";
?>
<form method="post" action="<?=$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]?>">
    <input type="text" name="id" placeholder="Facultad">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Guardar">
</form>
<?php
if(!empty($_POST)){
    $id = $_POST["id"];


    $usuario = new Log();
        $query = $usuario->mostrarPorid($id);
        if ($query->rowCount() != 1) {
            echo "Usuario y/o Contraseña incorrecto";
        } else {
            $datos = $query->fetchAll();
            foreach ($datos as $user) {
                //1er
                $entradafecha = $user["entrada"];
           }
        }

        ini_set('date.timezone','America/Lima'); 
        $salida = date("y-m-d H:i:s");
       
       $insertfech = new Salida();
       $insertfech->insertarsalida($entradafecha,$salida);


}



?>
```

> > Tengo dos clases Salida y Log la cual tienen include "ConexionBD.php"; y al tratar de unir las dos clases en un mismo archivo me da el siguiente errorFatal error: Cannot declare class ConexionBD, because the name is already in use in ¿Como puedo resolver el conflicto?

Comment: Cambia `include` por `include_once`

Comment: Si con  `include_once` funciona,Gracias